# Per class weighted loss for multiclass-multilabel classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, loss-function

I'm doing multiclass-multilabel classification. Namely, I have `N_labels` fully independent labels for each example, whereas each label may have `N_classes` different values (mutually exclusive). More concretely, each example is classified by `N_labels`-dimensional vector, while each vector components can by from the set `{0, 1, ..., N_classes}`

For example, if `N_labels = 5` and `N_classes = 3`, each example may be classified by the following tags:

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In addition, for each label I have very imbalance between different classes, namely 90% of examples in training set belong to set `0`. So, I'd like to perform weighted softmax cross entropy in order to compute loss for each label (and average afterwards).

Tried to use:

```
tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy # but it seems that it performs weightening between different label and not between classes for each label.

tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits,  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2  # does not have weightening option ever

tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits  # good only for binary classification
```

I'd like to find `compute_loss` function to compute loss in the following way:

```
loss = compute_loss(logits=my_logits, labels=my_labels, weights=my_weights)
```

where

```
my_logits is of shape [batch_size, N_labels, N_classes]
my_labels is of shape [batch_size, N_labels]
my_weight is of shape [N_labels, N_classes]
```

Note that each label may have different weights (for classes)

Comment: Can you provide an input `logits`, `labels`, `weights` and a desired output?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to stackoverflow. You mention that for each Label your Classes are mutually exclusive. I am not sure I get this from the example you provide.

Comment: @Gio, labels are not mutually exclusive. Each example is ALWAYS labeled with, say, 5 labels. And each label may have 3 different values (e.g. 0, 1, 2)

Comment: @gorjan, my input dimensions are:                                                       
my_logits.shape  = [batch_size, N_labels, N_classes]
my_labels.shape  = [batch_size, N_labels]
my_weight.shape  = [N_labels, N_classes]. Logits are real numbers, my_weight are positive numbers with sum(my_weight, axis=1) = ones(N_labels), while each component of my_labels may be each number from  {0, 1, ..., N_classes}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` It uses `multi_class_labels` just as you described, and have functionality to apply weights.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy

Example:
Suppose you have a multiclass multilabel classification problem, where you have 10 classes in total and label for single example look like this `[1, 3, 6]`, meaning example contains classes 1, 3 and 6.
You need to use k-hot encoding

```
labels = tf.reduce_max(tf.one_hot([1, 3, 6], 10, dtype=tf.int32), axis=0)
```

In this case output will be `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: not exactly. It is designed to solely multiclass classification when it is not combined with multilabel. But It can be used for each label separately and this is the way I doing it now invoking tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy() .

Comment: No, this actually the function for multiclass multilabel classification. Added example

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers